# The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I've deployed the application on Server (HostGator), and on Preview it gives me following error

> Server Error in '/' Application.   Configuration Error
>
> **Description**: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: This configuration section cannot be used at
>   this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access
>   to this section using  from an
>   inherited configuration file.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent the details of the application
>   error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could,
>   however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> Source File:
>   D:\InetPub\vhosts\accleague.org\admin.accleague.org\web.config
>   Line: 24

But when same application  deployed on another Server, it runs smoothly on 1st try.

Tried every possibility mentioned on internet but unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: "Current custom error settings for this application prevent the details..." - this indicated you need to set like `customErrors mode="On"` instead of `RemoteOnly`, then fetch all useful information from that error and include them in your question.